# DM An Invite with Guild Id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code which is supposed to DM the command user an invite to a guild with only the guild id, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

```
@client.command(name='dm')
async def _dm(ctx):
    guild = client.get_guild(712594852864589885)
    channel = guild.channels[0]
    invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1)
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

And here's the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command dm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 30, in _dm
    invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 732, in create_invite
    data = await self._state.http.create_invite(self.id, reason=reason, **fields)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 223, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10003): Unknown Channel

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10003): Unknown Channel
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Read documentation. 2. We don't know your server, so how can we know whether the channel exists? 3. Does your bot have permissions to create invites for that channel?

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to do it using this function:
await fetch_invite(url, *, with_counts=True).

more info on this function can be found in the [discord.py API refrence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild)